# What am I missing? Using AFNetworking to send movie file to php script

Tags: php, http-post, afnetworking

Hey friends I'm close to sending video from the iphone to my server, but for some reason my server has problems uploading the file to the file directory. I know I'm missing something simple someone can point out.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params  =  nil;
NSString*            command =  nil;
NSData*         videoPackage = [NSData  dataWithContentsOfURL:self.vidURL];
NSData*         imagePackage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage         imageNamed:@"videoShareDone.png"], 70);
command = @"videoUpload";

params  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:command, @"command",[_apManager uniqueID], @"unique_id",_apManager.userID, @"parent_id",@"blah",@"video",[NSDate date],@"ts_created", captionText.text,@"videoCaption",[ShareVideoController base64forData:imagePackage],@"coverImage", nil];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"Str33trider/" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
{
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoPackage name:@"uploadVideo" fileName:@"testthis.MOV" mimeType:@"video/mov"];
}];
     request.timeoutInterval           = 10.0;
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten,long long totalBytesWritten,long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
 {
     NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
 }];


[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    id JSON = [(AFJSONRequestOperation *)operation responseJSON];
    NSLog(@"responseString == %@, json code:%d", operation.responseString, [[[JSON    valueForKeyPath:@"status"] valueForKeyPath:@"code"] intValue]);
    if ([[[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"status"] valueForKeyPath:@"code"] intValue]==200)
    {

        NSLog(@"worked");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"failed");
    }
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);                                 
}];

[operation start];
```

AND here is my PHP CODE

```
function ulVideo ($unique_id, $parent_id, $video, $ts_created, $videoCaption, $coverImage)
{

      if(!empty($_FILES))
  {
          $target_path = '/Library/WebServer/Documents/Str33trider/userVideos/';
          $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadVideo'][$unique_id]); 

      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadVideo'][$unique_id], $target_path)) 
      {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadVideo'][$unique_id]). 
            " has been uploaded";
      } 
      else
      {
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
      }

   }
}
```

I get the response "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";

Comment: Your `$target_path` is incorrect you need to set it relative to your script ie "./userVideos/", or an absolute path "/home/website/public_html/userVideos/"

Comment: And check if the Apache's (if you're using Apache...) permissions for userVideos directory are properly set.

Comment: another note you should not be using the name of the video which is being uploaded as the file name in your system, use your `$unique_id` to avoid duplicate names for these videos

Comment: Ya the file permissions have been changed, and I am using my absolute directory.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? Otherwise some extra clues might be logged in php error log.